# Define the term mapping in relation to computer sciecne

Tags: mapping

Could someone explain what mapping means in laymen's terms and without using the actual word `map`. I understand that map is a method that is used to iterate through an array. Yet I often see the word `mapping` used to describe moving data from one place to another, I think I am confused.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to just google "Define mapping"? Even bing gets it. `an operation that associates each element of a given set (the domain) with one or more elements of a second set (the range).` So you're linking an x to a y or to multiple y.

Comment: Check out the wikipedia entry for this. It goes over it pretty well.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)

Comment: Yes I have, obviously yet I still don't quite understand the definitions I have found in relation to computer science.